# Best way for synonyms if data is stored outside dialogflow?

Tags: nlp, dialogflow-es

I want to create a chatbot. One of the intents is `who-is` which allows users to ask "Who is" for Arabic names to get information on a person. I have people stored in a database (firestore). I would like the user to say "Who is Saalih Uthaymeen?" But they may ask "Who is **Shaykh** Saalih **al**-'Uthaymeen?" as well. The names are different, but they're the same really. And they're close in spelling.

I noticed a synonyms feature in dialogflow, but I don't have the names stored in dialogflow so I don't know if it's useful. Since the synonyms have similar spelling, can't dialogflow help? Otherwise, I see the following options:

### Option 1. Manually create every name and its synonyms in dialogflow.

This is manual hard work. Even if I programmatically enter every name, I have to manually enter every synonym. And I have 2 or 3 hundred names.

### Option 2. Manually create synonyms in my database.

Basically, I have a table of people... so I would create a new table mapping every person to every synonym possible for his name. Since the spellings will be very similar, I'm confident this is a waste of work and time.

Is there any other option Dialogflow offers?